# Adding multiple attachments to outlook email based off elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the end of some code I will have a list like this and each time I run it there will be a different number of elements in the list (up to 8 elements):

`['9/Ma7_8.pdf', '8/Ma5_6.pdf', '9/Ma5_1.pdf']`

I need to be able to create an email which adds as many attachments as there are elements in the list and each attachment in the folder I am adding is called the same as the items in the list.  So for the list above, I will need to add three attachments called:

```
9/Ma7_8.pdf
8/Ma5_6.pdf
9/Ma5_1.pdf
```

I am using the following the do the email:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = ''
mail.CC = ''
mail.Subject = '...'
mail.Body = contents
```

My question is how do I write the code to add attachments?

If I was doing it manually then:

```
mail.Attachments.Add('9/Ma7_8.pdf')
mail.Attachments.Add('8/Ma5_6.pdf')
mail.Attachments.Add('9/Ma5_1.pdf')
```

Answer (score 4):

Loop over the list and attach every item:

```py
# attachments is your list of strings
for attachment in attachments:
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
```

Comment: This thread was recommended by the former editor of the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory